# Zero-copy exporting image using png++ or libpng

Tags: c++, libpng

Suppose I have a 2000 x 3000 24-bit RGB image stored in row-major, column, color-minor order.  I can export this with png++ as follows:

```
void export_png(const std::vector<uint8_t>& pixels, const std::string& pngfile) {
    png::image<png::rgb_pixel>> image(2000,3000);
    for (int y = 0; y < 3000; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < 2000; x++)
        {
            image[y][x].red = pixels[y*2000*3 + x*3 + 0];
            image[y][x].green = pixels[y*2000*3 + x*3 + 1];
            image[y][x].blue = pixels[y*2000*3 + x*3 + 2];
        }
    image.write(pngfile);
}
```

However this is inefficient because it copies the image data before exporting it, requiring at least an additional ~20 megabytes of memory more than should be needed, not to mention the time and memory bandwidth it takes to perform the copy.

Is there a way of exporting it directly from the pixels buffer without copying the data into a png::image first?  With png++ or libpng?  If so, what is the code for that?

Comment: Is the inefficiency actually a real *problem* in an optimized release build? If not, I'd say it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Where did you get the `pixels` vector from? Can you update that code to use `png::image` the whole way through so it doesn't need to be copied?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It's not really the time performance that is the concern, it is the space performance.  It requires twice as much memory than should otherwise be necessesary, and images can get quite big.  No, the optimizer cannot help.

Comment: @jtbandes: Assume the memory format of the source image data is constrained to be as specified by another part of the system.  The format described is quite common in a number of systems, and should not be suprising.  It cannot be changed (or cast) to png::image format.

Comment: If you want to use png++ then there's [example/pixel_generator.cpp](http://svn.sv.nongnu.org/svn/pngpp/trunk/example/pixel_generator.cpp) in the distribution which assembles the output row-by-row rather than needing the whole image in one go. Or you can write libpng code to write images row by row too.

Comment: @Rup: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.